# Finding the unsigned and out-of-tree loaded kernel modules?

Tags: kernel, security, malware

I just tried the

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted
```

command and the return value is 12289.

```
0     1           A module with a non-GPL license has been loaded, this
                  includes modules with no license.
                  Set by modutils >= 2.4.9 and module-init-tools
12    4096        An out-of-tree module has been loaded                           
13    8192        An unsigned module has been loaded in a kernel supporting
                  module signature
```

My questions are:

1. Is this normal?
2. How can i find which modules are unsigned, and find their binary files in order to scan them with virustotal?
3. What is an An out-of-tree module and how to find them and their corresponding binary files?